# Can't run mocha tests

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have some nodejs apps in some folder, and it seems i cannot run any mocha test, when i run npm test or mocha test i get this:

```
/home/jmartinez/uni/mis_practicas/p5-t1-egg-0-alu0100921038/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:84
exports.handleRequires = async (requires = []) =>
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jmartinez/uni/mis_practicas/p5-t1-egg-0-alu0100921038/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/options.js:15:16)
```

I tried reinstalling mocha again but nothing, the error persists, and i don't know how to fix it, i was just installing like everybody else. This errors happens across every nodejs app so its seems like a installation problem, but reinstalling didnt solve it.

I'm using node version v6.17.1

Comment: HI, Could you plz specify your node version?

Comment: have u checked if ur script has some typo, like missing braces?

Comment: Hi,have you updated mocha to latest?Mocha version 8.0.1 has some breaking changes.Check here:https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-changes

Comment: I don't have any typos. This problem occurs across all projects in my computer. I cannot even run a single command like "mocha", it returns the same error. Tried installing the latest version with npm install mocha@8.0.1 but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, seems like the version 6 for nodejs is quite old. I upgraded to the 12 and now its working.